# Cómo tener dos instancias de Jboss 5 ejecutándose en una misma máquina

Tags: xml, jboss-5.x, servidor

¡Hola!

Estoy un poco atorado dado que quiero tener dos instancias de Jboss ejecutándose en mi máquina, cuando levanto la primera instancia sin problema alguno, cabe destacar que ya configuure mi variable de entorno así como mi properties-service para que apunte a mi ip y puerto.

Ahora he intentando levantar una segunda instancia en mi máquina, ya configure mi variable de entorno asignando un puerto diferente al de la primera, así también mi properties-service.xml y mi server.xml

En mi primer instancia en el properties-service.xml:

```
system.com.host=192.168.2.15
        system.com.port=8480
```

En el bindings-jboss-beans.xml

```
 <bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
               <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
               <property name="bindingName">Port</property>
               <property name="port">1099</property>
               <property name="description">The listening socket for the Naming service</property>
            </bean>

<bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
               <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
               <property name="bindingName">RmiPort</property>
               <property name="port">1098</property>
               <property name="description">Socket Naming service uses to receive RMI requests from client proxies</property>
            </bean>
```

En mi server.xml

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8543" />
```

Ahora en mi segunda instancia lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

properties-service-xml:

```
system.com.host=192.168.2.15
            system.com.port=8383
```

En el bindings-jboss-beans.xml:

```
<bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
               <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
               <property name="bindingName">Port</property>
               <property name="port">1199</property>
               <property name="description">The listening socket for the Naming service</property>
            </bean>

            <bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
               <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
               <property name="bindingName">RmiPort</property>
               <property name="port">1195</property>
               <property name="description">Socket Naming service uses to receive RMI requests from client proxies</property>
            </bean>
```

En mi server.xml

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8383" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8543" />
```

Pero al querer levantar mi instancia obtengo el siguiente error:

```
    [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager_14] - Failed to create server socket on address 192.168.2.15 and port: 5,013
        [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Create: name=TransactionManager state=Configured
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.FatalError: [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager_9] - Could not get unique port.
```

Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola!

Encontré la solución, tenía que cambiar en mi archivo bindings-jboss-beans.xml la siguiente línea:

```
<parameter>${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-01}</parameter>
```

A:

```
<parameter>${jboss.service.binding.set:ports-02}</parameter>
```

Y en mi archivo server.xml

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" port="8010" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
         redirectPort="8543" />
```

A

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" port="8050" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
         redirectPort="8543" />
```

Con las modificaciones anteriores que había puesto en mi pregunta.

¡Saludos!